# QGIS Spatialite Performance/Data Limit

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I am trying to load a table with over 27mn rows from my spatialite DB using QGIS.

It has seem to hung while loading but I am not sure if it is just taking time to load everything.

Even if it loads, I suspect the performance will be slow.

Are there options to speed up the performance - i.e is there a more efficient format to load large number of datapoints with features? Or should I break my data into smaller chunks? i.e. its 2 years worth of data so instead of combining them i can do each year as a table/layer instead?

Note: The table has a spatial index on it

Comment: What are you doing with the data? Do you need all the 27 million features on the screen at the same time?

Comment: Yup - i am trying to create a heat map with the points - they are collision data

Comment: I believe that SpatiaLite is not the bottle neck but QGIS and it will be about as slow if you download the 27 million points from any other source. Save your data into PostGIS and have a try. But maybe there are better tools for visualizing big point datasets. Point cloud tools perhaps.

Comment: Thanks @user30184 for the advice again! - will explore some other tools as well like datashader

Comment: How many unique location points are there in the 27 mn row? Is it possible to divide the region to smaller areas?

Comment: Hi @mapperx! There is overlap in the positions but my plan was to use ALL 27mn to make a heat map. Instead I've cut my data into smaller chunks by different categories and features (6-7mn points per feature) they load but its really slow.